# VB.net 2012 - Retrieve Input from Input Box and change Text Property of Listbox to User Input

Tags: vb.net, listbox, inputbox

I'm extremely new to vb.net and programming in general so I hope I can get a very simple answer.

I wrote a input box that retrieves user input and stores it in the variable salesQty.

```
    salesQty =
    InputBox("Enter the sales quantity for " & itemListBox.Text, "Daily Sales Entry", "0")
```

Afterwards, I tried to set the text property of a Listbox to equal salesQty (assuming it will change the displayed text for the selected item), but it does not seem to be changing at all.

```
    salesQtyListBox.Text = salesQty
```

this is the entire code:

```
    Private Sub enterSalesQtyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enterSalesQtyButton.Click
    'Retrieve number of items in itemList Box and sets it as variable numItems
    Dim numItems As Integer = itemListBox.Items.Count

    'Declare index to use as counter
    Dim index As Integer

    Do While index < numItems
        index = index + 1
        Dim salesQty As String
        salesQty =
        InputBox("Enter the sales quantity for " & itemListBox.Text, "Daily Sales Entry", "0")

        'Changes Sales Quantity text to the users input that has been stored in SalesQty
        salesQtyListBox.Text = salesQty


        'Selects next index until all have been selected
        If itemListBox.SelectedIndex < numItems - 1 Then
            itemListBox.SelectedIndex = itemListBox.SelectedIndex + 1
        End If
    Loop

    enterSalesQtyButton.Enabled = False
    applyDailySalesButton.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it with my code? Does it works? If it isn't, I'l be glad to try and fix it according to your comments.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply! it's been a bit busy. I did try your code, but did not use it since I was actually specifically wanting to use a Do While instead of a For Next. However, I did take tips from it! For example, I didn't know  itemListBox.Items(i) =  was a thing and I ended out replacing salesQtyListBox.Text = salesQty with salesQtyListBox.Items(salesQtyListBox.SelectedIndex) = salesQty as well as other clean ups!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub enterSalesQtyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enterSalesQtyButton.Click

        ' Declare the varible outside the loop,
        ' because we dont need a new string every time.
        Dim salesQty As String = ""

        ' Loops through all the items in the list box.
        For i As Integer = 0 To itemListBox.Items.Count - 1

            ' Gets the user quantity for the current item (the "i" item of the list box).
            salesQty = InputBox("Enter the sales quantity for " & itemListBox.Items(i), "Daily Sales Entry", "0")

            ' Changes the "i" item according to the user data.
            itemListBox.Items(i) = salesQty
        Next

  End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

To add an item to a listbox you use the following code:

```
salesQtyListBox.items.add(salesQty)
```

I'm not sure if that totally answers your question but hopefully that should help.

Comment: The `Listbox` does have a `Text` property.

Comment: Does it? Ok, I'll edit accordingly, but either way, that's how you add an item to a list box... but I am extremely tired and may have misread the question so sorry... I'll edit accordingly

Comment: thank you for your help! I was actually trying to edit the text displayed on an existing item (which is 0) to change it to user input. is the only way to do it to add items or can i change the existing item?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this as well to be honest: the way I did it in my most recent program was to hold all of the items in a separate List(Of T) <- a variable type, and every time an item needed updating I wiped the list box and repopulated it from that list (as you can edit items in lists like they're an array) if it helps, you can have a look at the source here: https://github.com/hughesjs/Photo-Gift-Manager you probably want to look inside form1.vb :) if you need any more help just ask!

Comment: I found that I could update the text in a selected listbox item to a variable using salesQtyListBox.Items(salesQtyListBox.SelectedIndex) = salesQty

Comment: Awesome, glad you got that sorted :)